# Extjs 4: grid with more selType

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4, multi-select

I'm trying to figure out how to define an `Ext.grid.Panel` with different `selType`.

Actually, I need a grid that allows me to select both single cells and rows (with checkbox).
In the first case it needs to define `selType` config as `cellmodel` but in the second case it needs `selType` configured as `checkboxmodel`. Unfortunately, `selType` accepts a string not an array.

**So, is there any way to define different `selType` on a single grid?**

Comment: Baseclass your gridpanel and derive from it with different seltypes. I think that it is the only way you can accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it's possible to configure both a `selType` and a `selModel` in the same grid.

Here's an example:

```
// Store
var store = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
  fields: ['name', 'surname'] ,
  data: [
    {name: 'foo', surname: 'bar'} ,
    {name: 'too', surname: 'tar'} ,
    {name: 'zoo', surname: 'zar'} ,
    {name: 'coo', surname: 'car'} ,
    {name: 'boo', surname: 'bar'}
  ]
});
```

And then the grid:

```
// Dual selection grid
Ext.create ('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  title: 'My Grid' ,
  store: store ,
  width: 300 ,
  height: 300 ,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,

  selModel: Ext.create ('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel') ,
  selType: 'cellmodel' ,
  plugins: {
    ptype: 'cellediting' ,
    clicksToEdit: 1
  } ,

  columns: [{
    text: 'Name' ,
    dataIndex: 'name' ,
    editor: {
      xtype: 'textfield' ,
      allowBlank: false
    }
  } , {
    text: 'Surname' ,
    dataIndex: 'surname' ,
    editor: {
      xtype: 'textfield'
    }
  }]
});
```

But it's also possible to follow the way suggested by *A1rPun*, to put it better use more `selType` with hierarchy:

```
// Base grid with cellediting plugin and cellmodel as selType
Ext.define ('CellEditGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel' ,
  selType: 'cellmodel' ,
  plugins: {
    ptype: 'cellediting'
    clicksToEdit: 1
  }
});

// Adds the checkboxmodel selType to the base CellEditGrid
Ext.define ('DualSelectionGrid', {
  extend: 'CellEditGrid' ,
  selType: 'checkboxmodel' ,
  multiSelect: true
});

// Finally, we got our dual selection grid (cellmodel and checkboxmodel)
Ext.create ('DualSelectionGrid', {
  title: 'My Grid' ,
  store: store ,
  width: 300 ,
  height: 300 ,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,

  columns: [{
    text: 'Name' ,
    dataIndex: 'name' ,
    editor: {
      xtype: 'textfield' ,
      allowBlank: false
    }
  } , {
    text: 'Surname' ,
    dataIndex: 'surname' ,
    editor: {
      xtype: 'textfield'
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: +1 - the only thing that was still causing issues, was that in ExtJS 5 at least clicking trigger button for combobox, datefield editor was causing row selection toggle, and for this I have returned false on 'beforedeselect' event of CheckboxModel if editor.editing was true (in edit mode). I have used it only on 'beforedeselect' as I allow edit only on selected rows !

Answer (score -2):

It can't!

`grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().column`

Not the current editor.